# How I can access one class variables into another or different classes and different class variable access from one class

Tags: java, swing, class

I have a problem for accessing varible from different classes.i have a three
classes.first is login JFrame,sencod JFrame visible After login Success fully.in this 
Jframe have One Jbutton thats name is show "information about user"
`JButton btn = new JButton("inormation about user");`
then pressing this button new window is visible this Jframe Contains all userInformation

i am trying to solving this problem but i am fail.
i Access `LoginForm` class variable that is `usernametxt` into another class(`Userform`) in this class
iam printing `usernametxt` details on another class that is `UserForm` JLabel and its suceefull.
but this(`ProfileView1`)class varibel not aceesible in `UserForm` class. so help me;

this is my code:

```
public class LoginForm extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{ 
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
      {
        if(vali(cuser, password))
        {
            UserForm class2 = new UserForm(LoginForm.this);
            LoginForm.this.setVisible(false);

            usernametxt.setText(null);
            passwordtxt.setText(null);
          }
     }
}
```

this method used for accessing `JTextField` information on another class this is the method i am using;

```
 public String getJTextField()
 {
    return usernametxt.getText();
 }
```

this is my second class:

```
public class UserForm extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
  JLabel albl;
  private LoginForm log;
  JButton probtn;
  public UserForm(LoginForm log)
  {
       this. log = log;
       albl = new JLabel("");
       albl.setText(log.getJTextField());
           albl.setBounds(800, 10, 300, 30);
           add(albl);

       probtn = new JButton("inormation about user");
       probtn.setBounds(400, 370, 300, 170);
           add(probtn);
      }
}
```

this is my third class:

```
 public class ProfileView1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener
  {
JLabel firstlbl,lastlbl,userlbl,passlbl,genlbl,doblbl,typelbl,conlbl,ci1lbl,stlbl,moblbl,pinlbl,emlbl,qlbl,anslbl;
    JLabel flbl,llbl,ulbl,plbl,glbl,dlbl,tlbl,clbl,citlbl,slbl,mlbl,pilbl,elbl,qulbl,anlbl;
    public ProfileView1()
{
    setVisible(true);
    setBounds(360,30,700,600);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(null);

        Font f = new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,13);
    firstlbl = new JLabel("First Name :");
    firstlbl.setFont(f);
    lastlbl = new JLabel("Last Name :");
    lastlbl.setFont(f);
    userlbl = new JLabel("Username :");
    userlbl.setFont(f);
        passlbl = new JLabel("Password :");
    passlbl.setFont(f);
    genlbl = new JLabel("Gender :");
    genlbl.setFont(f);
    doblbl = new JLabel("Date of Birth :");
    doblbl.setFont(f);
    typelbl = new JLabel("User Type :");
    typelbl.setFont(f);
    conlbl = new JLabel("Country :");
    conlbl.setFont(f);
    ci1lbl = new JLabel("City :");
    ci1lbl.setFont(f);
    stlbl = new JLabel("State :");
    stlbl.setFont(f);
    moblbl = new JLabel("Mobile no :");
    moblbl.setFont(f);
    pinlbl = new JLabel("Pin no :");
    pinlbl.setFont(f);
    emlbl = new JLabel("E-mail :");
    emlbl.setFont(f);
    qlbl = new JLabel("Security Question :");
    qlbl.setFont(f);
        anslbl = new JLabel("Answer :");
    anslbl.setFont(f);

        flbl = new JLabel("");
    flbl.setFont(f);
    llbl = new JLabel("");
    llbl.setFont(f);
    ulbl = new JLabel("");
    ulbl.setFont(f);
    plbl = new JLabel("");
    plbl.setFont(f);
    glbl = new JLabel("" );
    glbl.setFont(f);
    dlbl = new JLabel("");
    dlbl.setFont(f);
    tlbl = new JLabel("");
    tlbl.setFont(f);
    clbl = new JLabel("");
    clbl.setFont(f);
    citlbl = new JLabel("");
    citlbl.setFont(f);
    slbl = new JLabel("");
    slbl.setFont(f);
    mlbl = new JLabel("");
    mlbl.setFont(f);
    pilbl = new JLabel("");
    pilbl.setFont(f);
    elbl = new JLabel("");
    elbl.setFont(f);
    qulbl = new JLabel("");
    qulbl.setFont(f);
    anlbl = new JLabel("");
    anlbl.setFont(f);

    firstlbl.setBounds(10,100,100,20);
    lastlbl.setBounds(10,130,100,20);
    userlbl.setBounds(10,160,100,20);
    passlbl.setBounds(10,190,100,20);
    genlbl.setBounds(10,220,100,20);
    doblbl.setBounds(10,250,100,20);
    typelbl.setBounds(10,280,100,20);
    conlbl.setBounds(10,310,100,20);
    ci1lbl.setBounds(230,310,100,20);
    stlbl.setBounds(430,310,100,20);
    moblbl.setBounds(10,340,100,20);
    pinlbl.setBounds(230,340,100,20);
    emlbl.setBounds(10,370,100,20);
    qlbl.setBounds(10,400,170,20);
    anslbl.setBounds(10,430,100,20);

    flbl.setBounds(90,100,100,20);
    llbl.setBounds(90,130,100,20);
    ulbl.setBounds(90,160,100,20);
    plbl.setBounds(90,190,100,20);
    glbl.setBounds(90,220,100,20);
    dlbl.setBounds(90,250,100,20);
    tlbl.setBounds(90,280,100,20);
    clbl.setBounds(90,310,100,20);
    citlbl.setBounds(310,310,100,20);
    slbl.setBounds(510,310,100,20);
    mlbl.setBounds(90,340,100,20);
    pilbl.setBounds(310,340,100,20);
    elbl.setBounds(90,370,100,20);
    qulbl.setBounds(90,400,100,20);
    anlbl.setBounds(90,430,100,20);


            add(firstlbl);
    add(lastlbl);
    add(userlbl);
    add(passlbl);
    add(genlbl);
    add(doblbl);
    add(typelbl);
    add(conlbl);
    add(ci1lbl);
    add(stlbl);
    add(moblbl);
    add(pinlbl);
    add(emlbl);
    add(anslbl);
    add(qlbl);

    add(flbl);
    add(llbl);
    add(ulbl);
    add(plbl);
    add(glbl);
    add(dlbl);
    add(tlbl);
    add(clbl);
    add(citlbl);
    add(slbl);
    add(mlbl);
    add(pilbl);

    add(elbl);
    add(qulbl);
    add(anlbl);
       }
    }
```

in this code iam using `Jlabels`. all blank `Jlabels` show userinformation which is present on `Database`
i have a problem for accessing this class varible on another class(`UserForm`)

this code:

```
public class UserForm extends JFrame implements ActionListener
 {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
      {
         if(ae.getSource().equals(probtn))
     {
         new ProfileView1();     
         }
      }
   }
```

this `probtn` pressed then another `JFrame` open(`ProfileView1`).this `JFrame`is open 
i dont no how to i access this class viraible(all showing userinformation `JLabels`)

i try this type:

```
public class UserForm extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
   private LoginForm log;
   private ProfileView1 pv;
   public UserForm(LoginForm log, ProfileView1 pv)
   {
  this.log = log;
  this.pv = pv;
    }
}
```

but error shows another class(`LoginForm`):

This is the error code which is showing error:

```
  ------> UserForm class2 = new UserForm(LoginForm.this,ProfileView.this);
  LoginForm.this.setVisible(false);
  setVisible(false);
```

its not working, actually this class(`ProfileView1`) open and show all user details after action on this button that's name is`probtn`this button present on the `UserForm`.

```
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
   {
     if(ae.getSource().equals(probtn))
 {
    new ProfileView1();  
     }
  }
```

i wish is that show all userdetails only one action(button is present on `UserForm` class)
please help me...............please.

i know you understand my question please help meeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the class UserForm to be able to access the fields in the class ProfileView1.

First, you need a field in UserForm that references your instance of ProfileView1.

```
public class UserForm extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
  private ProfileView1 proView1;     //*** add this line
  JLabel albl;
```

When you create the instance of ProfileView1, you need to set this field

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
{
     if(ae.getSource().equals(probtn))
     {
           this.proView1 = new ProfileView1();   //*** this line is changed
     }
}
```

Then in UserForm, you can now reference the non-private fields in this instance of  ProfileView1.  For example

```
String firstName = proView1.firstlbl.getText();
String gender = proView1.genlbl.getText();
```

Good luck!